# Can't get a friendly custom fault to feed back to the client in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I was throwing a new `FaultException("error");` and it went back to my client with the text 'error'.

Now I am taking it a step further where I want to use a `FaultContract` to do it properly.

Therefore I have created one called ServiceFault with the `[DataContract]` attribute and it simply has a `string ErrorMessage` property.

My code is this:

`ServiceFault serviceFault = new ServiceFault("Broken.");`

`throw new FaultException<ServiceFault>(serviceFault);`

I made a console app to test it, complete with try catch to capture the fault exception, but I just get:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

I imagine it's supposed to say that a fault exception occured, but it does not, I just get that.

Could I be missing something obvious? Perhaps a configuration option? I have implemented it using this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx

I should add that I have put `[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFault))]` onto the ServiceContract.

Also things to note: If I just throw a regular FaultException, the client handles it correctly.

When I throw a custom fault exception, it takes a very long time for the client to update the service / retrieve the MEX data, which is suspicious, even if I update twice in a row.

Comment: Does your client have a copy of the new service contract?

Comment: Yes, I update the service reference each time which downloads the full metadata (in theory) including all datacontracts and servicecontracts. If I explore the service on the client using the object browser, I can see my ServiceFault class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this and I'm leaving the question to stop others from having the same headache.

It was caused by the ServiceFault (my custom Fault class) not serializing properly.

The original class had two properties, a `string` and an `int` defined with a getter and a private setter.

Some part of that was massively confusing it, and so I set them to simple fields and rebuilt / updated service reference. It worked instantly without problem.

So be careful about your DataContracts to ensure they can be serialized correctly.

Comment: I think the private setter may have done it. In order to serialise and deserialise the class, all properties need to be public set and get.